# Finding a probability mass function of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability

> Four distinct integers are chosen randomly and without replacement
> from the first twelve positive integers. Let X be the random variable
> representing the second largest of the four selected integers, and let
> p(x) be the probability mass function of X. Determine p(x), for
> integer values of x, where p(x) > 0.

### Attempt:

Let's try evaluate $P(X=1)$, that is the probability that the second largest of the four selected is $1$. well this is not possible since $1$ must be smallest number of the four selected. By same reason we cant have $2$ or $12$, but $3$ is possible. Thus, $11 \geq X \geq 3$. Now, I am stuck in trying to find the mass function. This is my thought process but I still unable to undersand how to compute the mass function. I see that the sample space looks like

$$ S = \{ (i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4) : i_k \in \{1,2,...,12\}, i_k \neq i_j \} $$

if we want $P(X=x)$, then $x$ can any of the $i's$, so we multiply by $4$ the result. Suppose $x=i_1$, then we are trying to count the the strings $(i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4)$ such that $i_1 < i_2$ or $i_1 < i_3$ or $i_1 < i_4$. But now here we have 3 subcases and it keeps getting more complicated. What is the way to think about this problems?

Comment: Do you know the distribution of choosing the four distinct integers $\in [1,12]$? And do you about (discrete) ordered statistics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $\binom{12}4$ sets of four integers that you could choose.
How many have a given $a$ as second largest? Such a set is
$\{x_1,x_2,a,x_4\}$ where $\{x_1,x_2\}$ is a $2$-element subset of
$\{1,\ldots,a-1\}$ (how many of them are there?) and $x_4\in\{a+1,\ldots,12\}$. If there are $N_1$ possible $\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $N_2$
possible $x_4$ then $P(X=a)=N_1N_2\binom{12}4^{-1}$.